# How to make ARGB transparency using bitwise operators

Tags: math, colors, transparency, alphablending

I need to make transparency, having 2 pixels:

`pixel1: {A, R, G, B} - foreground pixel

pixel2: {A, R, G, B} - background pixel`

A,R,G,B are Byte values

each color is represented by byte value

now I'm calculating transparency as:

`newR = pixel2_R * alpha / 255 + pixel1_R * (255 - alpha) / 255

newG = pixel2_G * alpha / 255 + pixel1_G * (255 - alpha) / 255

newB = pixel2_B * alpha / 255 + pixel1_B * (255 - alpha) / 255`

but it is too slow
I need to do it with bitwise operators (**AND,OR,XOR, NEGATION, BIT MOVE**)

I want to do it on Windows Phone 7 XNA

---attached C# code---

```
    public static uint GetPixelForOpacity(uint reduceOpacityLevel, uint pixelBackground, uint pixelForeground, uint pixelCanvasAlpha)
    {
        byte surfaceR = (byte)((pixelForeground & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        byte surfaceG = (byte)((pixelForeground & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
        byte surfaceB = (byte)((pixelForeground & 0x000000FF));

        byte sourceR = (byte)((pixelBackground & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        byte sourceG = (byte)((pixelBackground & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
        byte sourceB = (byte)((pixelBackground & 0x000000FF));

        uint newR = sourceR * pixelCanvasAlpha / 256 + surfaceR * (255 - pixelCanvasAlpha) / 256;
        uint newG = sourceG * pixelCanvasAlpha / 256 + surfaceG * (255 - pixelCanvasAlpha) / 256;
        uint newB = sourceB * pixelCanvasAlpha / 256 + surfaceB * (255 - pixelCanvasAlpha) / 256;

        return (uint)255 << 24 | newR << 16 | newG << 8 | newB;
    }
```

Comment: Changing division form 255 to 256 improved code a lot. For 8 FPS to 14 FPS in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do an 8 bit alpha blend using only bitwise operations, unless you basically re-invent multiplication with basic ops (8 shift-adds).

You can do two methods as mentioned in other answers: use 256 instead of 255, or use a lookup table. Both have issues, but you can mitigate them. It really depends on what architecture you're doing this on: the relative speed of multiply, divide, shift, add and memory loads. In any case:

Lookup table: a trivial 256x256 lookup table is 64KB. This will thrash your data cache and end up being very slow. I wouldn't recommend it unless your CPU has an abysmally slow multiplier, but does have low latency RAM. You can improve performance by throwing away some alpha bits, e.g A>>3, resulting in 32x256=8KB of lookup, which has a better chance of fitting in cache.

Use 256 instead of 255: the idea being divide by 256 is just a shift right by 8. This will be slightly off and tend to round down, darkening the image slightly, e.g if R=255, A=255 then (R*A)/256 = 254. You can *cheat* a little and do this: (R*A+R+A)/256 or just (R*A+R)/256 or (R*A+A)/256 = 255. Or, scale A to 0..256 first, e.g: A = (256*A)/255. That's just one expensive divide-by-255 instead of 6. Then, (R*A)/256 = 255.

Comment: using shift instead of division is a bad idea. `((unsigned char)a)>>8` will be 0 regardless of the value of `a`. Unless you start using 16 bit integers.

Comment: Also, there are integer overflows everywhere in your calculations, e.g. R=255, A=255, R*A/256 = 0 (because 255*255=1 mod 256)

Comment: You can't do any of this if you're restricting to 8 bit operations only. The method using (R*A+R+A)/256 fits in 16 bits. The method scaling alpha to 256 also fits in 16 bits. The examples in the question assume larger than 8 bit intermediate values, so I think it's OK to use that.

Comment: I agreed with John on this. Most processors/compilers use 16/32 bit results anyway even if the source operands are 8 bits, so the recommendation is great. In a x86 processor, if you code this in assembly you even get the 256 division completely for free, since the result is just hanging around in the AH register - you don't even have to bit-shift it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done with the same precision using only those operators. Your best bet is, I reckon, using a LUT (as long as the LUT can fit in the CPU cache, otherwise it might even be slower)

```
// allocate the LUT (64KB)
unsigned char lut[256*256] __cacheline_aligned; // __cacheline_aligned is a GCC-ism

// macro to access the LUT
#define LUT(pixel, alpha) (lut[(alpha)*256+(pixel)])

// precompute the LUT
for (int alpha_value=0; alpha_value<256; alpha_value++) {
  for (int pixel_value=0; pixel_value<256; pixel_value++) {
    LUT(pixel_value, alpha_value) = (unsigned char)((double)(pixel_value) * (double)(alpha_value) / 255.0));
  }
}

// in the loop
unsigned char ialpha = 255-alpha;
newR = LUT(pixel2_R, alpha) + LUT(pixel1_R, ialpha);
newG = LUT(pixel2_G, alpha) + LUT(pixel1_G, ialpha);
newB = LUT(pixel2_B, alpha) + LUT(pixel1_B, ialpha);
```

otherwise you should try vectorizing your code. But to do that you should at least provide us with more info on your CPU architecture and compiler. Keep in mind that your compiler might be able to vectorize automatically, if provided with the right options.

Comment: you can also factor out 255 division (which is costly)

Comment: @aaa the division is done only during the LUT creation so it's hardly costly. Actually it can be even done at compile time... (i.e. storing the LUT as a static array)

Comment: A 64KB lookup table is expensive due to cache thrashing. That's bigger than the L1 cache in all mobile phone platforms I know of.

Comment: @John actually, it depends on whether alpha is constant throughtout the loop. In case it is, it needs only 512bytes of cache.

Comment: Hmm, the question shows per-pixel alpha, but the formula is just 'alpha' used twice, which indicates it's not. You're right - if it's constant alpha then at worst you cache-miss on 256 bytes, which is nothing.